# Requirements to run LAXUNIX.SH - LaunchAnywhere (tm) version 14.0

Tags: linux, files, java, executable

I am trying to install a program. After installation was done, I tried to click on the installed file and I got this:

```
LAXUNIX.SH - LaunchAnywhere (tm) version 14.0
```

***To run this script you will need to have the following:***

> - a Java VM installed
> - a Java-Style properties file having the same name as this script with the suffix .lax. If this script is appended to the self-extractor, it will look for the properties file in the directory specified by $seLaxPath; otherwise, it will look in the same directory that this script is in.
> - a Java program in the file "lax.jar".

**The .lax property file must contain at least the following properties:**

> - lax.class.path classpath (do not include the environment variable $CLASSPATH)
> - lax.nl.java.launcher.main.class (main class of LaunchAnywhere Executable).

I have installed a Java VM, but I didn't understand what do they mean by the rest: a **java-style properties**, how to create it? and a Java program in the file lax.jar? Does anyone here know how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I gather this script is a part of a commercial piece of software InstallAnywhere, which has a forum [here](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/forumdisplay.php?213-InstallAnywhere). I've found a similar script [here](https://github.com/stevengill/completeui/blob/master/server/build/installanywhere/resource/launchanywheres/unix/laxunix.sh). I *guess* what happened when you clicked that file was that you opened it, and what you post in your question is not all that was there, as there was much more in that script and even what you posted looked different. (Am I right?)

The other script I found, which is an earlier version, is rather long and complex, so without much analysis I can give you the following advise.

1. As there's the dedicated forum, you should do your research there and they should be more knowledgable to give you any advice.

But I'll add a few more points as I'vo got into this topic.

2. I don't know how it's supposed to by run, I mean where in the sofware chain is its place. If it's executed by something else or should be executed itself. If you want to execute it yourself, then don't click on it, but check **from the command line** if it has **executable permissions** and then **execute it**. It should have some debugging built-in, so you should get some hints that will help you further in case it doesn't work.
3. The properties file in question from what I can see [here](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-199724.html) requires the form of:

   ```
   property=value
   ```

   And so you need to define at least these two:

   ```
   lax.class.path=<classpath (do not include the environment variable $CLASSPATH)>
   lax.nl.java.launcher.main.class=<main class of LaunchAnywhere Executable>
   ```

   How do you create it? There are many ways in Linux. You can try `vi` (difficult), `vim` (less difficult), `nano` (rather easy), or you can use a GUI one like `gedit`.
4. As for the `.jar` file, it is a Java archive file.

Hopefully it helps a bit. Again, with any questions better consult the dedicated vendor forum.

Comment: Hello, first I want to thank you for spending some time answering my question. as you have mentioned this is not the whole file. Actually the script that you have attached in your comment is exactly the whole file that I got while installing my program. But can you please clarify how can I benefit from the install anywhere software you mentioned in your comment? thank you again

Comment: @ola I don't know how you can benefit. I don't even know what that software is.